# Create empty zip file using Zip4j library

Tags: java, android, zip4j

I want to know how to create empty zip file using Zip4j library.

Shouldn't this line of code be enough to create an empty zip file? When I tried it, it doesn't work.

```
ZipFile zipFile1 = new ZipFile(zipFilePath);
```

My question is for this lib : https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j

### Edit

An answer told me to create ZipFile and add file in it then remove that file. I just want to create ZipFile directly without any complications, just function get path like "/storage/emulated/0/ZipPro/zipPro.zip" and create this zip file "zipPro.zip".

Comment: `addFile` followed by `removeFile`. Then save that `empty.zip` as resource and use `Files.copy` to create empty zip files.

Comment: I am just curious as to why you would want to create an empty zip file? Zip4j does not support it out of the box. You probably want to consider the hack in the comment above - i.e., to add a file and then remove that file to/from the zip

Comment: @JoopEggen hi any another way to create zip file without add an then remove file?

Comment: @SrikanthReddyLingala is Zip4j  doesn't support to create empty zip file?

Comment: If zip4j forgot to implement that, you can use java.util.zip ZipFile or as said use a manually created empty zip.

Comment: @JoopEggen I know an empty zip can be created with java.util.zip but I want to use only the zip4j library

Comment: `new ZipFile("filename.zip").addFiles(new File[0]);` you probably already tried first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            File file = new File("path/to/folder/FOLDER_NAME");
            if(!file.exists())
                file.mkdir();
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
            zipFile.extractAll(file.getPath());
```

Comment: This should be down voted as you try to use a directory as file.

Comment: @blackapps your affirmation is based on what?

Comment: @FARS see me edit what i want?

Comment: @FARS you answer [extractAll] file from Zip file and i don't want that, i wanna just create empty zip file by only [path] like this path /storage/emulated/0/ZipPro/zipPro.zip